# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular

[image]

May I ask how to solve this problem?

Comment: Ensure that the value you call `.map()` on, is not `void` ;-)

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';    This path has map!  my code : this.post(url,data,{headers: headers}).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
       console.log(data);  
     });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you actually want

```
this.http.post(
```

but hard to tell from the tiny information fragments your question provides.